# Weird behaviour in HTTP call when hybrid Android app is launched from background

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, xmlhttprequest, angular5

Probably, the title of the question is considered as **not a valid question** but we have spent 4-5 days debugging the issue. Here is the context:

1. We have an Hybrid app (Ionic3 + Cordova)
2. We have a Telecom Network Operator in Europe
3. We have provided them a URL to be whitelisted which is header enriched (by that Telecom operator) with user's mobile number whenever that URL is hit when user is using the mobile network of that operator
4. That URL must be a **http** URL not **https**
5. So we added a Angular HTTP interceptor in our codebase to convert https to http for that URL only
6. The Android mobile app hits to that URL as soon as the app launches

**Now here is working/expected behaviour:**

When app is launched freshly (was not in background or was killed by the home screen), the app hits that URL and the network operator identifies that URL and we receive the mobile number of the user.

**Here is the scenario which is not working:**

Now, we press the back button in Android and exit the app gracefully. That means Android app is in background & killed. Now we again launch the app from the app's icon and that header enrichment doesn't work.

Now, we added various tcp level logs using `tcpflow` command:

```
sudo tcpflow -i eth0 port 443 -C -e http
sudo tcpflow -i eth0 port 80 -C -e http
```

And we identified that whenever the app is relaunched from background (hence hitting to that URL), **the entire request is encrypted** but the URL we **receive is http URL** and the **port is 443**.

We added various logs in our http interceptor and in the Android phone but we are not able to identify the root cause. Can someone point a different direction to look for the issue.

**Edit 1:**

1. Tested on 5 different devices with different Android OS and device manufacturer
2. Android app is a **release** build

Comment: I'm not really sure what your actual issue is, but "That means Android app is in background & killed" is not correct. When pressing back button, the app is paused, not killed, the webview is not destroyed. Different internal behaviour. 

Have you tried placing your networking logic inside document.addEventListener("resume", function() {}); block instead?

Comment: As of now, when we press the back button, our app goes to background and killed because when we relaunch the app, everything is happening from the scratch like loading Splash & background music. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, apps, in the background, are killed after a certain period of time. Newer versions of iOS keep apps alive for a maximum of 3 minutes, for android it's however long it takes for the app to doze off or when the OS requires extra ram. If your app is killed instantly when entering the background, then you have a bug that causes your app to crash when entering background. That could also be the root cause of your issue. I suggest you try to debug it with Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts but as of now, this is just on Android and our Android apps get killed immediately we press the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another research of the full day, I was able to figure out the root cause of this problem.

Here I got the issue following the clues (in case someone gets help from it):

1. I got to know about the `launchMode` type of Android app
2. I stared Googling with Android's `launchMode` and this http encryption
3. I landed to a blog post reading **[Android O to drop insure TLS version fallback](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-o-to-drop-insecure-tls-version.html)**
4. I Googled more about **TLS version fallback**
5. Googling different keywords, led me to [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) where I read about **Networking and HTTP(S) Connectivity** where I saw a new concept (for me) i.e. TLS renegotiation.
6. I started reading about TLS renegotiation and started relating it with `Nginx` & it's change logs so I figured out this is something related to Nginx & HTTP communication.
7. Till this point of time, I was only looking at the HTTP block in Nginx server configuration but I took a look at HTTPs block in Nginx and saw a unclear (to me) header configuration `Strict-Transport-Security` which was set to `max-age=31536000 always`
8. I dug about this header configuration and entire issue got cleared up immediately in my mind that this is not an issue, this is the default behaviour that when a browser see a successful HTTPs request and see that header, the next non-HTTP request is by default attempted with HTTPs and that was the issue we were having.

I removed the header (first reduced it's value to just 10 millisecond, so browsers can take effect) and tested my app with the same scenario, everything started working as expected.